# Carregar lista por partes utilizando AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Quero retornar uma consulta utilizando AngularJS e, ao apresentar na tela utilizando um `ng-Repeat`, exibir apenas os 10 primeiros registros, e acrescentar de 5 em 5 registros, utilizando o scrollbar* ou apenas clicando em um botão.

Ex: Lojas Virtuais que vão mostrando os produtos quando vai descendo o scrollbar. Mas tenho a preferencia de que fosse usando uma ação clicando em um botão.

Comment: Por favor, especifique melhor a sua pergunta, parece que esta faltando algo, coloque um exemplo mais claro e objetivo para que possamos auxilia-lo melhor

Comment: Olá Arthur, veja se consegue entender os exemplos desta diretiva https://binarymuse.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/, ela faz exatamente o que você quer, ai se tiver alguma dúvida podemos ajudá-lo. Aqui é o exemplo com consulta no backend https://binarymuse.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/demo_async.html.

Comment: Você quer basicamente fazer igual o que o facebook faz só que vai exibir 10 registros e depois rolar de 5 em 5 registros por vez, é isso?

Comment: Exatamento galera, ja tinha visto utilizando Jquery usando função scrollbar, porem como sou no no Angular JS, é mais difícil pra achar!

Comment: O Angular JS trabalha bem com jquery. ele tem até um minimizado: Jqlite: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Comment: Eu tinha preferencia que fosse usando uma ação clicando em um botão.

Comment: dá uma olhada aqui: http://infiniteajaxscroll.com/

Comment: aqui tem mais: https://binarymuse.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/

Comment: A ideia é somente ocultar os demais registros ou a cada vez que clicar no botão fazer uma chamada Ajax para carregar mais dados?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Para criar a sua função, basta inserir um novo botão e fazer com que ele chame a função de "carregar mais". Por exemplo:

html:

```
<div ng-click="carregaMais()" ng-if="botaoAtivo">Carregar mais</div>
```

função (no meu caso, está no controller):

```
var valInicial = 10, //Valor inicial a ser carregado
    valAtualiza = 5, //Quantidade a ser atualizada a cada clique
    valAtual = valInicial;
    totalItem = $scope.lista.length; //length total da lista de dados que você possui

$scope.botaoAtivo = true; //Mostra o botão por padrão
$scope.limiteValor = valInicial; //Usado no DOM para limitar exibição na tabela

function loadMore() {
    valAtual += valAtualiza;
    $scope.limiteValor = valAtual;
    if (valAtual >= totalItem) {
        $scope.botaoAtivo = false; //Desativa o botao de carregar mais
        return;
    };
};

$scope.carregaMais = function() { //Chamando a função de 'carregar mais' com clique de botão
    loadMore();
};
```

Está tudo bem documentado, acho que vai ser fácil de entender. Para criar a função de carrega com o scroll, você vai precisar de outros métodos. Inclusive, já existem muitos outros prontos, [como este aqui](https://github.com/ifwe/infinite-scroll), que basta você chamar a mesma função usada no clique, ambas irão funcionar.

E a sua tabela, ou seja lá como você está exibindo os dados, deve possuir um ng-repeat``com a propriedade `limitTo: XX`, que irá limitar a exibição de acordo com aquele valor, ficando assim:

```
ng-repeat="lista in minhaLista | limitTo:limiteValor"
```

o nome 'limiteValor' é apenas referência ao valor iniciado dentro do `controller`, mas você pode definir no próprio DOM, sem problema. Assim ele fica mais dinâmico e menos propício a erros.

Uma observação importante é sobre o uso de `AngularJs` e `jQuery`. Assim como você, no começo eu me tentava muito a usar as funções em `jQuery`, pois achava 'mais fácil'. Mas evite isso. O `AngularJs` possui diversas ferramentas e métodos que você pode fazer bem dizer tudo que o `jQuery` faz. Então, tente se manter apenas no `AngularJs`.